# Created pages does not appear in "Content"

Tags: orchardcms

When I add a page to the site of Orchard CMS, my created pages don't appear in the menu content, how do I fix this gap?

I looked through all the documentation, but have not found how to handle this problem, maybe I can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Check in content definitions that the content type is creatable.

Comment: I can create a pages, but I can not view created through the admin panel.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Go to Content Definitions, edit the content type, and look for a checkbox named Creatable.